# Android "Can't playthis video" while buffering

Tags: android, timeout, alert, android-videoview, buffering

I have a VideoView and sometimes, depending on network performance, it displays the "Can't play this video" alert even if the video was already playing.
The impression I have is that, if the network performance is poor and the buffer runs out, it automatically shows the alert.
If I leave it without pressing "ok" and the buffer fills up again, the video continues playing, and then pressing ok takes back to the video.
So it's clearly not a matter of formats or codecs, but it's like the player is too sensitive with the alert.
Is there a way of disabling the alert or increasing the timeout before displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

It will happen may be your video size will not be as per solution if it will be higher then you will get this alert.